# Rails - how to refer to a class that is in another module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

If I have a controller that is inheriting from Devise, and I want to access a module outside of Devise (for example if I have a products model), how can I access it within the controller that is inheriting from Devise? The following gives me an `NameError uninitialized constant`:

```
 class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    define foo
       Products.find(1)
    end
 end

 class ProductsController < ApplicationController

 end
```

I've tried:

```
ApplicationController::Products.find(1)
ActiveRecord::Base::Products.find(1)
```

Comment: which constant is uninitialized here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for such thing. Models are not inside any module.

I think you might be confused and your model class is actually `Product` instead of `Products` at least that's how you should name it by the convension

Comment: he's using `Product.find` though

Comment: ups. I guess I need to sleep. It seemed Products to me

Comment: Sorry, I had the typo Products at first and then I edited it.

Comment: Oh, I was worried now. Good to know I was right. So could you show the error message?

Comment: and can you tell where is Product class defined?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, your answer is correct.  I had a typo in my code.

Answer (score 4):

Is Product a name of a model?

If so you can access any top level constant with the following syntax

```
::Product
```

This way ruby will not search the current module context first

Comment: I was thinking about this too but since this is in rails, will `Product` be top level or under the application scope? So say something like `Store::Product` if your application is called `Store`

Comment: Product would be toplevel, and so are all Rails models. Rails doesn't magically namespace them :) you can check by running Object.const_defined?('Product')